# controlling the peak of a cos function

Tags: trigonometry

how would you write a cos function that would create one large curve over the period 1 to 365 that peaked at 172? The y value would be between 1 and 100.

I tryed $100\cos((2\pi)/365+172)+50$ but that does not look right

Comment: I see no variable

Comment: Be more precise. Call the function $f(x)$. What values do you want for $f(0),f(365)$? Is 172 an $x$ value or a $y$ value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ y(d) = 100 \cos ( 2 \pi (d - 172)/365 ), (0< d< 365).$$

where $d$ is the day number of year.

Please remember the sine wave form

$$ y(x)= A \sin (\frac {2 \pi x-\phi)}{\lambda} )$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is my thought on it. Since your y-values are between 1 and 100, we are balancing the cosine curve at its average, which is $50.5$ The amplitude would be $49.5$ So the function is going to look like $y=49.5cos(\frac{2{\pi}x}{365}+c)+50.5$ You want this curve to peak for $x=172$ so that results in the equation $cos(\frac{2{\pi}172}{365}+c)=1$ (Check: Where did I get that $1$ from?) Then from here you can solve your phaseshift $c=-\frac{344{\pi}}{365}$ This should do it